# Android app size varies a lot with device

Tags: java, android, gradle, build, android-gradle-plugin

**Problem**

I build my app and installed the same apk on 5 android devices. The apk is 3MB big, but the size when installed varies a lot from device to device. I want to know why that is and how I can counter that.

**Testing**

- On two different nexus 5's (Android 6.0.1) the installed size is 30MB. specs: http://www.gsmarena.com/lg_nexus_5-5705.php
- On my Acer Liquid Z220 (lollipop) the installed size is 14MB if installed in the internal storage or 11MB if I move it to external. specs: http://www.gsmarena.com/acer_liquid_z220-7074.php
- On the Wiko U Feel Lite (Android 6.0.1) the installed size is 3MB (same as the apk). specs: http://www.gsmarena.com/wiko_u_feel_lite-8204.php
- On the Acer Liquid Z630 (Android 6) the installed size is 4.5MB. specs: http://www.gsmarena.com/acer_liquid_z630-7528.php

Before I release my app on the play store I want to figuere out what causes the app size to vary that much and what I can do to decrease the maximum size. I also find it counter intuitive that the installed size is the biggest on my two nexus 5's, because they have the latest android versions of the tested phones and my app uses the latest android appcompat and design library.

EDIT: I noticed the instalation folder contains the original apk + an odex file. On my nexus 5 the .odex file is about 25MB big. After a quick google I also found that odex files help speed up your app. Another thing I noticed was that if I removed the .odex file the app still functioned perfectly and it was a lot smaller.

This however is not the solution to my problem because I can't ask the users of my app to go root their phone to remove the .odex file. Is there any way to reduce the .odex file size?

**Code**

Notice I am using jack to be able to use lambdas in my code. And minify is not enabled because jack handles shrinking so proguard is no longer necessary (source: https://source.android.com/source/jack).

Also worth noting is that `compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])` only adds a small <2k lines library which is only 36KB. You can find this library here: https://github.com/flaghacker/SuperTTTApi

*build.gradle:*

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.henrykvdb.sttt"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 8
        versionName "0.0.10"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        jackOptions {
            enabled true
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'

    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.4'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:10.2.4'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:10.2.4'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

*top level build.gradle:*

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

*Entire project:*

https://github.com/henrykvdb/SuperTTTAndroid

*APK:*

https://github.com/henrykvdb/SuperTTTAndroid/releases/tag/v0.0.10

Comment: I asked for the specs to test a hypothesis that when the app installs it copies only the resources, particularly images, supported by the device. So if you have an image resource of various resolutions to support different screen sizes, I imagine that the installer can select which ones to extract from the APK. I am not sure if any installers actually do this, though.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice All my image resources for all different resolutions are less then 30KB combined so I doubt that is the case as the installed size goes up to 30MB on certain devices.

Comment: @Henrykvdb That seems to shoot holes through my first hypothesis.